# Apache Camel sending multiple REST requests without timeout

Tags: timeout, apache-camel, restlet

i'm trying to send many REST requests via camel. I expected a sequential
processing but after 11 requests the test stopped and it started producing timeouts.

Is it really necessary to configure the restlet thread pool settings described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35080432/apache-camel-connection-pool-timeout-with-restlet-even-after-configuring-compone)? Why is the processing stopping after some requests? I don't want parallelism...

Thank you in advance

@RunWith(CamelSpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MultipleRestRequestsTest.ContextConfig.class}, loader = CamelSpringDelegatingTestContextLoader.class)
public class MultipleRestRequestsTest extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

```
@EndpointInject(uri = "mock:result")
protected MockEndpoint resultEndpoint;

@Produce(uri = "direct:start")
protected ProducerTemplate template;

@Test
public void testMultipleRequests() throws Exception {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i++) {
        template.sendBody(i);

    }

    resultEndpoint.setExpectedCount(1000);
    resultEndpoint.assertIsNotSatisfied(50000);
}

@Configuration
public static class ContextConfig extends SingleRouteCamelConfiguration {
    @Bean(name={"restlet"})
    public RestletComponent restlet() {
        RestletComponent restlet = new RestletComponent();
        restlet.setMaxThreads(100);
        restlet.setThreadMaxIdleTimeMs(10000);
        restlet.setMaxQueued(20);
        return restlet;
    }

    @Bean
    public RouteBuilder route() {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                from("direct:start")
                        .log("Request ${body}")
                        .to("restlet://http://localhost:8080/mock-service")
                        .to("mock:result");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

}

> INFORMATION: Starting the Apache HTTP client 2017-06-07 08:06:27,761 
>   INFO SpringCamelContext:2835 - Apache Camel 2.17.0 (CamelContext:
>   camel-1) started in 0.440 seconds
>
> - 2017-06-07 08:06:27,784 
>     INFO route1:159 - Request 1
> - 2017-06-07 08:06:27,926  INFO
>     route1:159 - Request 2
> - 2017-06-07 08:06:27,931  INFO
>     route1:159 - Request 3
> - 2017-06-07 08:06:27,935  INFO
>     route1:159 - Request 4
> - 2017-06-07 08:06:27,940  INFO
>     route1:159 - Request 5
> - 2017-06-07 08:06:27,944  INFO
>     route1:159 - Request 6
> - 2017-06-07 08:06:27,949  INFO
>     route1:159 - Request 7
> - 2017-06-07 08:06:27,953  INFO
>     route1:159 - Request 8
> - 2017-06-07 08:06:27,958  INFO
>     route1:159 - Request 9
> - 2017-06-07 08:06:27,962  INFO
>     route1:159 - Request 10
> - 2017-06-07 08:06:27,967  INFO
>     route1:159 - Request 11
>
> Jun 07, 2017 8:06:57 AM
>   org.restlet.ext.httpclient.internal.HttpMethodCall sendRequest
>   WARNUNG: An error occurred during the communication with the remote
>   HTTP server. org.apache.http.conn.ConnectionPoolTimeoutException:
>   Timeout waiting for connection from pool  at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute.getEntryBlocking(ConnPoolByRoute.java:412)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute$1.getPoolEntry(ConnPoolByRoute.java:298)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager$1.getConnection(ThreadSafeClientConnManager.java:238)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:422)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:863)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:106)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
>     at
>   org.restlet.ext.httpclient.internal.HttpMethodCall.sendRequest(HttpMethodCall.java:339)
>     at
>   org.restlet.ext.httpclient.internal.HttpMethodCall.sendRequest(HttpMethodCall.java:363)
>     at
>   org.restlet.engine.adapter.ClientAdapter.commit(ClientAdapter.java:81)
>     at
>   org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpClientHelper.handle(HttpClientHelper.java:119)
>     at org.restlet.Client.handle(Client.java:153)   at
>   org.restlet.Restlet.handle(Restlet.java:342)  at
>   org.restlet.Restlet.handle(Restlet.java:355)

Comment: Its likely also because you send too many requests to the same host, often a HTTP client may have a limit on max requests to same host.

Comment: A manual processor with ClientResource resource = new ClientResource(...) works without any problem. The restlet component does something different.

Comment: The rest client is created only once per endpoint - this could explain this behaviour (https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-restlet/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/restlet/RestletProducer.java#L61)

Comment: As long as I do not have a solution, I use the custom processor with a manual HTTP client